# How to call Linux commands through WSL in Windows command line?

Tags: shortcut, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I would like to use `ls`, and many other Linux tools, from the command line on Windows 10. I know that there is GnuWin32 and other binary replacements, but none of those works as elegantly as the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL); including the update mechanisms.

With WSL, one can call `ls ...` from the command line via `bash -c "ls ..."`, which works great. Ideally, however, I would just type `ls` on the command line. I can create an `ls.bat` which basically does `@bash -c "ls %*"` - but I would have to do that for every single command I want to export. Is there a more direct way of exporting `ls` (and many others) to the command line?

Comment: The bash commands available in WSL are not intended for use outside of WSL. I would be surprised if that is ever implemented.

Comment: @ifconfig Well, it doesn't have be intended or implemented. I would be happy with a one-liner aliasing "many" well-known Linux commands to the respective WSL commands.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Apparently this was the [most requested feature for WSL](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsl/2016/10/19/windows-and-ubuntu-interoperability/), and Microsoft now supports this feature. To use linux commands from within Command Prompt (or PowerShell), just prefix the command with `wsl`. So, for example, here's how you run `ls` from CMD.

```
C:\temp> wsl ls
<- contents of C:\temp ->
```

Or here's how you update package lists.

```
C:\temp> wsl sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for username:
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [94.5 kB]
```

More details can be found in the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/interop#run-linux-tools-from-a-windows-command-line).
I'm not sure if you are looking for a solution which doesn't involve any kind of prefixing. If that's the case, I don't know of any solution yet.

Comment: `wsl ls ...` is certainly more typable than `bash -c "ls ..."`, so yes, this answers my question.

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft doesn't directly support what you're asking for, however...

- You can create a "[Console Alias](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-aliases)" using doskey.exe, but these
  Console Aliases are not persistent (when you open a new Command
  Prompt window they're all gone).
- `CMD /?` informs us of the following two Registry keys: `HKey_Local_Machine\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun` and `HKey_Current_User\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun`, which (as long as the `/D` option wasn't specified) will both be checked for contents to run (in that order) when a new Command Prompt window is opened.

If we put these two things together with a `FOR` loop, and a nice, easily customizable file in your user folder, we can get a pretty close approximation of what I think you want.
I'm going to put this in HKLM, and reference a file in `%USERPROFILE%`, called `exportlinuxcommands`, so that it's available to all users, but easily customizable on a per-user basis, as well as only functional for users who set it up. If you only want it for one user, or don't want it to be customizable on a per-user basis, you'll have to modify the instructions a bit.

1. Open the Registry Editor
2. Go to `HKey_Local_Machine\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor`
3. Right-click on an empty portion of the window, and choose "New" > "String Value" (or "Expandable String Value", but the expansions seem a little pointless when you realize that the Command Processor will expand them after it reads the value anyway.)
4. Name it "AutoRun" (without the quotes)
5. Double-click on the new value you just created
6. Enter `IF EXIST %USERPROFILE%\exportlinuxcommands FOR /F %i in (%USERPROFILE%\exportlinuxcommands) DO @doskey %i=bash -c "%i $*"` as the "Value data".

Now you just need to make a file in your `%USERPROFILE%` folder (i.e. `C:\Users\YourUserName`) called `exportlinuxcommands`, with each Linux command you want an alias to on a separate line. For example:

```
ls
rm
cat
```

Want to remove one? Remove it from the file, and it won't be there in the next Command Prompt window you open.
Want to add another later? Just add it to the file on it's own line, and the next time you open up a Command Prompt window, it'll be there.

Comment: That's pretty neat! I am still working on starting `bash` in the current working directory (seem to be working most of the times, but not always), but apart from that, that's very close to what I want to do. I guess that getting this to work with the pipe (`some-windows.exe | grep`) would be somewhat more complex, though.

Comment: When does bash not start in the current working directory?

Comment: Unfortunately doskey aliases don't work unless they're at the beginning of the command line. This is an intentional feature which allows you to make an alias with the same name as a dos command and still be able to run the command itself by adding a blank space to the beginning of the line.

Comment: If anyone knows of another way to make an 'alias' on Windows, I'd be interested to see it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [windowsBash](https://github.com/aleppos/windowsBash)

Run the following command inside Windows Bash to generate shortcuts for commands

`wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aleppos/windowsBash/master/windowsBash -P /usr/bin && chmod 0777 /usr/bin/windowsBash && windowsBash`

Then just add the following directory to your path in Windows
* C:\windowsBash

When you want to update the commands list just run the Shell file again

`windowsBash`

Comment: This does not seem to be maintained any longer: `Invalid command line option: -c`

Answer (score -1):

In windows terminal click on settings to open settings.json
you will find your distro settings there. Add this line:

```
"startingDirectory": "\\\\wsl$\\{YOUR DISTRO}\\home\\{YourUsername}"
```